# Objects to be passed between client and server using employee class

Tags: java, sockets, server

I need to modify the code so that an object is passed between the client and the server rather than individual data. This requires me to define my own class Employee and create objects of the Employee class to pass between the client and the server

Client class

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MultiClient extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    // IO streams
    private DataOutputStream toServer;
    private DataInputStream fromServer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee no1 = new Employee();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MultiClient frame = new MultiClient();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setTitle("Work Hard Client");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MultiClient() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 650);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
        jta.setBounds(12, 391, 408, 199);
        contentPane.add(jta);

        try {
            // Create a socket to connect to the server
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8000);

            // Create an input stream to receive data from the server
            fromServer = new DataInputStream(
                    socket.getInputStream());

            // Create an output stream to send data to the server
            toServer =
                    new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            jta.append(ex.toString() + '\n');
        }

        JLabel lblEnterMonths = new JLabel("Enter months:");
        lblEnterMonths.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblEnterMonths.setBounds(12, 36, 119, 29);
        contentPane.add(lblEnterMonths);

        JLabel lblEnterDays = new JLabel("Enter days:");
        lblEnterDays.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblEnterDays.setBounds(12, 100, 119, 29);
        contentPane.add(lblEnterDays);

        JLabel lblEnterPayrate = new JLabel("Enter payrate:");
        lblEnterPayrate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblEnterPayrate.setBounds(12, 154, 119, 29);
        contentPane.add(lblEnterPayrate);

        JLabel lblEnterHours = new JLabel("Enter hours:");
        lblEnterHours.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblEnterHours.setBounds(12, 208, 119, 29);
        contentPane.add(lblEnterHours);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        textField.setBounds(233, 28, 187, 46);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBounds(233, 92, 187, 46);
        contentPane.add(textField_1);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        textField_2.setBounds(233, 146, 187, 46);
        contentPane.add(textField_2);

        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        textField_3.setColumns(10);
        textField_3.setBounds(233, 200, 187, 46);
        contentPane.add(textField_3);

        JButton btnCalulatePay = new JButton("Calulate Pay");

        btnCalulatePay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    int noMonths = (int)
                            ((Double.parseDouble(textField.getText()))
                                    );
                    toServer.writeInt(noMonths);

                    int noDays = (int)
                            ((Double.parseDouble(textField_1.getText()))
                                    );
                    toServer.writeInt(noDays);

                    double payRate = (double)
                            ((Double.parseDouble(textField_2.getText()))
                                    );      
                    toServer.writeDouble(payRate);

                    double  hours = (double)
                            ((Double.parseDouble(textField_3.getText()))
                                    );
                    toServer.writeDouble(hours);

                    double sum = (noMonths*noDays)*(payRate*hours);
                    // Send the pay to the server
                    toServer.flush();
                    // Get area pay the server
                    double Pay = fromServer.readDouble();

                    jta.append("Pay is " + sum+ "\n");
                    jta.append("Pay received from the server is "
                            + sum + '\n');
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex);
                }
            }
        });
        btnCalulatePay.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        btnCalulatePay.setBounds(12, 305, 119, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnCalulatePay);

        JButton btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
        btnClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                textField.setText(null);
                textField_1.setText(null);
                textField_2.setText(null);
                textField_3.setText(null);
            }
        });
        btnClear.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        btnClear.setBounds(143, 305, 75, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnClear);

        JButton btnHelp = new JButton("Help");
        btnHelp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Message", "Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);  

            }
        });
        btnHelp.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        btnHelp.setBounds(233, 305, 75, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnHelp);

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnExit.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        btnExit.setBounds(332, 306, 75, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnExit);

    }
}
```

Server class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MultiClientServer extends JFrame {
  private JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Employee employee = null;
    new MultiClientServer();

  }

  public MultiClientServer() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new JScrollPane(jta), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setTitle("Work Hard Server");
    setSize(500, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true); // It is necessary to show the frame here!

    try {
      ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
      jta.append("MultiThreadServer started at " + new Date() + '\n');

      int clientNo = 1;

      while (true) {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

        HandleAClient task = new HandleAClient(socket);


        new Thread(task).start();

        clientNo++;
      }
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
      System.err.println(ex);
    }
  }


  class HandleAClient implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket; 

    /** Construct a thread */
    public HandleAClient(Socket socket) {
      this.socket = socket;
    }

    /** Run a thread */
    public void run() {
      try {

        DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(
          socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(
          socket.getOutputStream());


        while (true) {

          int noMonths = inputFromClient.readInt();
          int noDays = inputFromClient.readInt();
          double payRate = inputFromClient.readDouble();
          double hours = inputFromClient.readDouble();


        double sum = (noMonths*noDays)*(payRate*hours);

          outputToClient.writeDouble(sum);
          jta.append("Months received from client: " +
                  noMonths + '\n');
          jta.append("Days received from client: " +
                  noDays + '\n');
          jta.append("Rate received from client: " +
                  payRate + '\n');
          jta.append("Hours received from client: " +
                  hours + '\n');

          jta.append("pay calculated and sent is: " +
                  sum + '\n');
        }
      }
      catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Employee Class

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private int noMonths;
    private int noDays;
    private double payRate;
    private double hours;

    Employee( int mon, int days, double pay, double hour ) 
    {
        noMonths = mon;
        noDays = days;
        payRate = pay;
        hours = hour;
    }

    public Employee() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getNoMonths() {
        return noMonths;
    }

    public void setNoMonths(int noMonths) {
        this.noMonths = noMonths;
    }

    public int getNoDays() {
        return noDays;
    }

    public void setNoDays(int noDays) {
        this.noDays = noDays;
    }

    public double getPayRate() {
        return payRate;
    }

    public void setPayRate(double payRate) {
        this.payRate = payRate;
    }

    public double getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(double hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need to make employee class is the only way to make the other 2 classes work.

Comment: @Jason2020 You can just use `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest would be to use something such as [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/) which will change your object into XML format.

You would then use [`writeUTF(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF-java.lang.String-) to write your `Employee` object as an XML string and then use [`readUTF()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF) to get your XML string back.

You could then use XStream again to change it back into your object.

EDIT:

As per your comment, my understanding is that you need to change the code so that you do not send the object's property values, but rather write the object itself.

The method I propose changes the `Employee` object into an XML string. You would then write the XML string onto the stream and read it back, thus ending up with an XML string on the server's side.

You would then use XStream again to change your XML string into its corresponding object.

You could probably use other methods in which you serialize the `Employee` class as an array of bytes and you transmit that. The problem with that approach, in my opinion is that it can cause problems down the line should you want to connect to the system through other languages since the serialization might be off.

XML serialization at least allows you to manually parse the object, which provides you with a fall back plan.

Comment: Well I got confused, sorry could explain more?